# How can i access a variable from one function to another?

Tags: python, json, function, global-variables, call

```
def move(self):
      z = self.comboBox.currentText()
      print(z)
      Hospital = newtest.my_function()
      i = Hospital.index(z)
      print('The index of :', i)
      user = newuser.my_function()
      global (user[i])
      print (user[i])

  return user[i]


def my_doc():

    url = 'https://test.com/steth/get-list'
    myobj = {'mongoId': 'user[i]'}
    x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
    y=x.json();
    print(y)
my_doc()
```

I need to get user[i] in the second function  my_doc.so i made user[i] global.But it is showing syntax error as

```
global (user[i])
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syn
```

Comment: how about add an argument to my_doc() as: def my_doc(user = user): ....

Answer (score 0):

Just get the return of one function, and input it into the other.

```py
class Obj:
    def func1(self):
        return "something"

    # Assuming func2 is inside class.
    def func2_class(self, something):
        print(something)

# Assuming func2 is outside class.
def func2(something):
    print(something)

obj = Obj()
something = obj.func1()

func2(something)     # Outside class.
obj.func2(something) # Inside class.
```